# Generic for type guard function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'd like to create function which filters list of two types into two separate lists of unique type. I've succeed to create it with hardcoded types:

```
interface TypeA {
  kind: 'typeA';
}
interface TypeB {
  kind: 'typeB';
}
filterMixedList(mixedList$: Observable<(TypeA | TypeB)[]>): Observable<TypeA[]> {
  return mixedList$.pipe(
    map(items => items
      .filter((item): item is TypeA => item.kind === 'typeA')),
  );
}
```

But is there way to create generic to avoid hardcoding? Please, help.

PS: here is the minimal reproducible example:
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-generic-type-guard?file=index.ts)

Comment: Can the generic rely on the `kind` property? If not, how does it distinguish?

Comment: Both types have it, but how it can be connected with generics or type guard I don't know... Simple generics is quite clear for me, but with type guard - too complicated ( 
PS: all the docs about that highly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, maybe my question was unclear. Can solutions to this problem assume that the generic function will only be used with types that have a `kind` property that distinguishes them?

Comment: Type guards only serve to narrow the types TS knows at compile time. However, in your case you want a test that checks the types at runtime. The type system doesn't exist at that point, so you can only hardcode those or materialise these types into something more concrete like classes or variables.

Comment: Yes, it can. Two types with "kind" property.

Comment: T.J. Crowder,  VLAZ - thank you for your attention, I'll leave it as is.

Comment: There's a way to generify this but I don't have your dependencies in my environment; can you please edit this code to form a [mcve] that works in a standalone IDE *or* provide a link to a web IDE with the relevant dependencies configured?  The [TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play) doesn't easily let you import from `rxjs/operators` so I'm ‍♂️.  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz, Here it is:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-generic-type-guard?file=index.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to make this generic is to pass in the type guard function.  That would look like this:

```
function typeFromMixedList<T, U extends T>(
  mixedList$: Observable<T[]>,
  guard: (item: T) => item is U
): Observable<U[]> {
  return mixedList$.pipe(map(items => items.filter(guard)));
}
```

Or, if you know that the type you are checking is a [discriminated union](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions), you can pass in the discriminant key and the value to check:

```
function typeFromDiscriminatedUnionList<
  T,
  K extends keyof T,
  V extends (T[K]) & (string | number | undefined | null)
>(
  mixedList$: Observable<T[]>,
  key: K,
  val: V
): Observable<Extract<T, { [P in K]?: V }>[]> {
  return mixedList$.pipe(
    map(items =>
      items.filter(
        (item): item is Extract<T, { [P in K]?: V }> => item[key] === val
      )
    )
  );
}
```

Either way should work for your example:

```
typeFromMixedList(of([a, b]), (x): x is TypeA => x.kind === "typeA").subscribe(
  v => (dataDivA.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(v))
);

typeFromDiscriminatedUnionList(of([a, b]), "kind", "typeB").subscribe(
  v => (dataDivB.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(v))
);
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Stackblitz link to code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-generic-type-guard-toudxo)